# 'Object is possibly null' after destructuring with default value

Tags: typescript

I'm rather new to TypeScript. I have an interface like so:

```
export interface Stop {
  sequenceNumber?: number | null;
}
```

I then try to do this:

```
  stops.sort((stopA: Stop, stopB: Stop) => {
    const { sequenceNumber: seqA = 0 } = stopA;
    const { sequenceNumber: seqB = 0 } = stopB;
    return seqA - seqB;
  });
```

It complains with `Object is possibly 'null'` for both `seqA` and `seqB`, even though I have destructured them with a default value of `0`.
Why does it do this and how do people usually overcome this?

Even more confusing is the fact that if I write it like so:

```
const seqA = stopA.sequenceNumber || 0;
const seqB = stopB.sequenceNumber || 0;
```

Typescript does not complain. Aren't both ways effectively doing the same thing?

Comment: You have a default value for squenceNumber but for Lint that param is optional because of "?", can be "null" and at the end you are substracting the object itself. I'm not sure what you want to do. Can you please explain it a little bi?

Comment: This is a basic sorting method to sort the stops by order of their `sequenceNumber`.  I'm just confused why it is complaining that `seqA` and `seqB` can be null when I've set an initial default value for them.

Comment: In the interface there's a number | null it says that given property can be null in some cases, that's why. In other subject, I understand the sorting algorithm but it is expecting a number as you cannot substract and object out of another object, I think you should evaluate the property that you want to sort(i.e., seqA.sequenceNumber - seqB.sequenceNumber). In the last thing you posted there is an assignation of the value of you object's property but if it's null it will assing "0", that's why  it's not complaining